# Google Geocoding Api

Tags: java

El problema que tengo es que estoi haciendo unas pruebas con la api de Geocoding para poder coger latitud y longitud al poner una dirección.

Si configuro la api que este abierta totalmente me funciona correctamente al hacer la petición, pero si configuro la restricción por la ip del servidor no me funciona en la web al hacer la peticion, pero si que me funciona en el servidor.

Alguien me puede explicar como puedo hacer para que me funcione en la web?

La llamada es asi.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + $('#Direccion').val() + ' ' + $('#Poblacion').val() +'&key=YOUR_APIKEY',
    method: "GET",
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status === "REQUEST_DENIED") {
            $('#mapa').text("ERROR: Verifica que la dirección este bien.");
        } else {
            $('#mapa').text(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    }
});
```

Si cargo la Url desde el propio servidor si me devuelve pero si la ago en la web como visitante desde cualquier PC me devuelve este error:

{error_message: "This IP, site or mobile application is not authori…://URL de la pagina web", results: Array(0), status: "REQUEST_DENIED"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de estar haciendo pruebas ya tengo la solución.
Primero en el archivo HTML cargamos el script de google

```
  <script async diferir src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_APIKEY"></script>
```

Despues en el archivo de js donde tenemos todos los eventos de la página creamos la siguiente función.

```
function getLocation() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: latlng
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), mapOptions);
codeAddress();
```

}
De tal manera que a la que hacemos click en un boton llamamos a dicha función para que cargue el mapa. Para hacer la llamada en a Google maps pasandole la calle y la población y que nos devuelva la latitud y longitud para crear el mapa y poner la chicheta haremos lo siguiente.

```
function codeAddress() {
var address = $('#Direccion').val() + '+' + $('#Poblacion').val();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        $('#mapa').fadeIn();
    } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
```

}

De esta manera funciona todo correctamente. En la configuración de la api de Google maps le ponemos la restricción que solamente funcione con dicho dominio si queremos le podremos agregar otros dominios. Pero solamente funciona con dicha restricción, esta api no funciona con la restricción de IP del servidor lo dice en la documentación de google.